# Snowflake is not recognizing a column in a table created in Alteryx

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, alteryx

I have an Alteryx workflow which selects everything from a snowflake table, adds a RecordId column to the table, then uploads the result back to snowflake with a new name.

The problem is: Snowflake does not recognize the RecordID column.

If i use a `SELECT * FROM NUMBERED_TABLE` it successfully reads the entire table, displaying every field, including the RecordID.

But if I try to select with `SELECT RECORDID FROM NUMBERED_TABLE` I get the message `SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 invalid identifier 'RECORDID'`

From the UI, Snowflake says the column is indeed called RECORDID.

Trying to rename the column doesn't work either. It simply says the RECORDID column doesn't exist.

I already tried recreating the table by creating a new one based on itself, it's still not recognizing it.

Comment: It probably won't matter, but can you try `SELECT RecordId` instead of `SELECT RECORDID` ? Just want to rule out any weird quirks arising from Alteryx being involved in column creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is `SELECT RECORDID FROM NUMBERED_TABLE` but you note a couple of times the name is `RecordID`.

Snowflake is case sensitive for object names so `RECORDID` and `RecordID` can be two different columns in the same table. Snowflake implicitly uppercases object names, so if you run query `SELECT RecordID FROM NUMBERED_TABLE` Snowflake will implicitly convert that to `SELECT RECORDID FROM NUMBERED_TABLE`. If the column is in fact `RecordID`, it will report that it can't find `RECORDID`. If you have a mixed-case column name, the way to prevent the implicit uppercasing is to wrap the object name in double quotes:

`select "RecordID" from NUMBERED_TABLE;`

Most ETL partners will wrap object names in quotes for Snowflake. I've seen Alteryx do that for Snowflake, so that's probably what's happening here if it's `RecordID` in the source database.